# laptop screen display random patterns of pink and green

Tags: display

My laptop screen displays random patterns on green and pink depending on the angle of lid. I have to press at the bottom of the lid or top of the lid to get it right again.

[image: scrrenshot of image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One or more of the video cables connecting your laptop's display to the body of the laptop is loose or damaged.

From the look of those black circles, the LCD itself has probably been damaged as well. You will probably need to replace the screen, or the laptop itself.

Comment: Are you referring to the cable that connects LCD to motherboard?

Comment: @ashwinids Yes. Check that cable is connected properly and not damaged.